# Probability of a household being covid-19 contact traced

Tags: probability

The United Kingdom is moving to a system of contact tracing where people who test positive for the virus will be asked who they've been in contact with and the chain of contacts traced.

Assuming each household has a fixed $1/1000$ weekly chance of catching the virus (regardless of how much or little contact they have), contact tracers trace contacts back 1 week, and each household has contact with $X$ other households, in terms of $X$, what is the weekly probability that a given household will be contact traced?

I think the number of households who is they test positive the given household will be contact traced is something like $1 + X + (X^2)/2 + (X^3)/2^2 + (X^4)/2^3 + \dots$ But that goes on to infinity. How do I simplify it?

In the above attempt, the $1$ is the given household themselves, $X$ is first order contacts, $(X^2)/2$ is second order contacts etc.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think I did provide context? Can you be more specific with whats lacking in the context provided? I have added some thoughts and working out as requested.

Comment: I think that your question is fine now.

Comment: The infinite series, as written converges to a finite number: you can probably see that it can be rewritten as $-1 + 2(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (X/2)^k)$. The sum within the brackets is a geometric series, there are many questions here on MSE about how to evaluate them if you don't already know. HOWEVER: what is not clear to me is how you arrived at this series for the number of people to test. Where do the powers of 2 come from?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake: it converges to a finite number if and only if X < 2.

Comment: However there is an other issue. While the *number* of people that need to be traced might be finite, the time needed to identify all of them still looks infinite and so only a small portion of it can be done within a week. In other words: your model needs to incorporate a term for the time the tracing takes

Comment: @Vincent the time limit is specified in the question as one week. I divide by 2 because if household A has contact with B1 and B2, and B1 has contact with C1 and C2 but the contact with B1 and C1 was after the contact with B1 and A, it doesn't matter. So on average (I think) only about half the congtacts in each stage of the chain matter

Comment: So the first circle (just A) is 1. The second circle is X. The third circle is X*X/2. The forth is (X*X/2)/2. Or maybe (X*X/2)/4 because in the next circle more of the contacts would be earlier in the week? Im not sure.

Comment: Let's say X is 3. Adding up each circle is going to be 1 + 3 + 3*3/2 +  (3*3/2) * 3/4 + ((3*3/2) * 3/4) * 3/8 + (((3*3/2) * 3/4) * 3/8) * 3/16 + .....

Comment: Thats 1 + 3 + 3.375 + 1.27 + 0.24 = 13.4

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1+%2B+X+%2B+X*X%2F2+%2B+%28X*X%2F2%29+*+X%2F4+%2B+%28%28X*X%2F2%29+*+X%2F4%29+*+X%2F8+%2B+%28%28%28X*X%2F2%29+*+X%2F4%29+*+X%2F8%29+*+X%2F16+%2B+%28+%28%28%28X*X%2F2%29+*+X%2F4%29+*+X%2F8%29+*+X%2F16%29+*X%2F32%2C+X%3D0..7

Comment: I think what this is telling me is that for each extra contact per household included, the pool doubles

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the best thing to tell you as there are two aspects here. One is: does my mathematical model accurately reflect reality? The other is: how to evaluate the infinite sum showing up in the model?

As for the first: if the model predict that contact tracers will track down and interview infinitely many people in one week time, then it stands to reason that somewhere during the week the reality and model start to look quite different. We could try and build a better model but this is tricky, so instead I focus on the other question: how to evaluate the sum

$$S = 1 + X + X^2/2 + X^3/2^2 + X^4/2^3 + X^5/2^4 + \ldots $$

First step: it is a bit annoying that the powers of $X$ are different from the powers of $2$. What to do about that? Well $X^2/2$ is $X^2/2^2$ multiplied by 2. $X^3/2^2$ is $X^3/2^3$ multiplied with 2. So we can rewrite in a more pleasant form:

$$S = 1 + 2(X/2 + X^2/2^2 + X^3/2^3 + \ldots)$$

To make things even more pleasant we can introduce a new letter. Say $Y = X/2$. Then we get

$$S = 1 + 2*(Y + Y^2 + Y^3 + Y^4 + Y^5 + \ldots)$$

Yaaay! No fractions anymore. Now things are getting easy. Let's make it even easier for ourselves and first try to understand the thing inside the brackets, the sum:

$$T = Y + Y^2 + Y^3 + \ldots$$

Now the first thing to notice is: if $Y \geq 1$ then $Y^2 \geq 1$ AND $Y^3 \geq 1$ etc etc so we add up infinitely many things that are all at least 1 so the answer is infinity. Done. We have our answer to the mathematical question. How to make the model more realistic is a different question.

But what now if $Y < 1?$ (Or equivalently $X < 2$, remembering that $Y = X/2$.)

That is when things get interesting.

Look at the sum

$$U = 1 + Y + Y^2 + Y^3 + \ldots$$

How does this relate to the sum $T$ above? Well on one hand you can say:

$$U = 1 + T$$

On the other hand you can say:

$$U = T/Y$$

Both seem equally defensible. So who is right?

The answer is: both!

We get $T/Y = 1 + T$ and this gives us a way of solving $T$ using high school algebra:

$$T = Y + YT$$
$$T - YT = Y$$
$$(1 - Y)T = Y$$
$$T = \frac{Y}{1-Y}$$

Here we see that this can only make sense if $Y < 1$: we don't want a negative number out of a sum of positive numbers. But this fits nicely with our earlier observation that the computation can only makes sense when $Y < 1$ since otherwise $T$ is infinite. So nothing new here, really.

Now

$$S = 1 + 2T = \frac{1 - Y}{1 - Y} + \frac{2Y}{1 - Y} = \frac{1 + Y}{1 - Y} = \frac{1 + 2X}{1 - 2X}$$

Very nice, but remember this equation can only make sense if $X < 2$ because otherwise we already had that $S$ is infinite.

The great thing is that in fact for every $0 \leq X < 2$ we *do* have that this equation holds. Just try it out for $X = 1$:

$$1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + \ldots$$

gets arbitrarily close to 3. Just compute a few more terms if you don't believe it, eventually you will be convinced that the limit is 3.

And plugging $X = 1$ in in our formula we find

$$\frac{1 + X/2}{1 - X/2} = \frac{3/2}{1/2} = 3$$

Other example: when $X = 1.2$  our formula predicts that infinite ends up at

$$\frac{1 + X/2}{1 - X/2} = \frac{1.6}{0.4} = 4$$

And feeding the first, say 30, terms of the infinite sum into wolfram alfa will convince you that this is indeed correct.

I just taught you this trick because it can be helpful in many situation, but perhaps not so much in this.

Here is a related riddle. I have two parents. They each have two parents and so on. It follows that by the time the dinosaurs died out there were many many more people alive than are today, and that is just counting my own predecessors, not those of everyone else alive now. How is this possible?